# Open graph custom story review, without facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm confused about whether it's compulsory to use facebook login on a site, if I just want a user to be able to **explicitly** publish a custom story.

For example, I've created a custom "Review" action. It hasn't been approved yet, so it only works for my developer/test accounts.

I want a user to share this story on facebook:
[image: request to share buttons]

If yes is clicked, `FB.ui(method: 'share_open_graph', ... )` is called, which brings up this dialog:

[image: review share permission]

Is this alone not an acceptable case for using/approving a custom story?

When I attempt to submit my action for review, I'm forced to declare that my app uses facebook login. I have no need to call `FB.login()` anywhere. So does the above process implicitly constitute as facebook login? If not, why do I need to shoehorn facebook login into my app, when this is all I want to accomplish?

**Edit - Evidence:** Note how *Submit for Review* is greyed out, until I tick this checkbox:
[image: submit greyed out]

Here's a snippet from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/opengraph):

> This example Open Graph action was rejected for:
>
> - Listing a website that does not use Facebook Login...

Comment: You don't need to add Facebook login to your app

Comment: @WizKid edited my question to give evidence for my claim, am I interpreting things wrong? Is there a setting that needs changing?

Comment: I've also failed reviews twice, and I've been warned, which is why I'm watching my step.

Comment: You said you use Facebook login so if they reject you for not using it then it is because they don't find it or don't understand your instructions

Comment: @WizKid https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process#platforms says, “Websites & mobile websites must use Facebook Login” – and those instructions are specific to submitting an Open Graph story for review (and don’t pertain to permission review at the same time), are they not? The point in using the Share dialog to publish a story is to not have to use permissions and require login, I think. I filed a documentation bug for this earlier today, asking for some clarification (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1398981997094738)

Comment: @WizKid OK. I don't believe I've said I'm using facebook login anywhere. How do I make it clear that I'm not using facebook login? I've only ticked my story for review: http://imgur.com/co83d8I . Yet I'm still forced to acknowledge that I use facebook login before submitting. Also, as Cbro kindly pointed out, that quote is taken directly from the OG review documentation. Really confused here...is there anything I could read that would clear this up?

Comment: Sorry I mixed your post up with someone else.

Comment: @CBroe thanks! Also noticed, that documentation needs some work, it's missing a "Step 3"

Comment: @WizKid it's cool yo. So what's the plan here?

Comment: i am stuck with the same issue, have you figured this out?

Comment: @AndreiG. I feel your pain. Check the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a [really laborious review process](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/705484572915495/?search_id), which culminated in [some direct support](https://developers.facebook.com/direct-support/question/1477977362494801/), I managed to get it approved.

It took about 5 submissions, with each one pretty much identical, until it finally went through.

Even though you're not using facebook login, just tick this anyways:

*I have tested that all platforms load and use facebook login*

Good luck.

PS: [This could be relevant](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1398981997094738/?search_id).

Comment: this is what i did yesterday, submitted just in case, and unexpectedly got it approved today. I already removed all facebook features from my app, going to add them back. Perchance i got lucky, or caught your wave of facebook support pressure, in any case, thanks for your post!